# Required number of transitions to reach steady state of Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider a Markov chain with initial condition $I$ and transition matrix $T$. The steady state condition $S$ solves the equation $ST=S$. But is it possible to compute the minimum number of transitions which result in the steady state condition? In other words, how to compute $n$ such that $IT^n=S$?

Comment: Many (non-reguar) Markov chains have no steady state, and many (most?) that do merely approach a steady state but never arrive there after finitely many transitions. Do you have some kind of prior condition on your transition matrix?

Comment: The 4X4 transition matrix is [1-r0 r0 0 0;0 1-r1 r1 0;0 0 1-r2 r2;r3 0 0 1-r3], where r0, r1, r2, and r3 are given probabilities between 0 and 1. I can obtain the steady state condition in terms of r0, r1, r2, and r3, so I am sure that the steady state condition exists; however, as you mentioned, n (the required number of transitions to reach to the steady state condition) can be very large or infinity. Could you please let me know how I can check it? The initial condition is [1 0 0 0].

Comment: For general initial conditions I, indeed I*(T^n) is never exactly S. Explicit computations when ri does not depend on i are straightforward, which show this in this case.